# Linq query that reduces a subset of duplicates to a single value within a larger set?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a linq command that will filter out duplicates that appear in a sequence?

Example with '4':

```
Original { 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 4 4 4 8 9 4 4 4 }
Filtered { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 4 8 9 4 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to svick's answer, except with side effects to avoid the cons and reverse:

```
int[] source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 8, 9, 4, 4, 4 };

List<int> result = new List<int> { source.First() };
source.Aggregate((acc, c) =>
    {
        if (acc != c)
            result.Add(c);
        return c;
    });
```

**Edit:** No longer needs the `source.First()` as per mquander's concern:

```
int[] source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 8, 9, 4, 4, 4 };

List<int> result = new List<int>();
result.Add(
    source.Aggregate((acc, c) =>
    {
        if (acc != c)
            result.Add(acc);
        return c;
    })
);
```

I think I still like Danny's solution the most.

Comment: I would be all over this solution except that the initial .First() kills it for operating on any lazy sequence.

Comment: There we go, check it out now :D

Answer (score 5):

Not really.  I'd write this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveDuplicates(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    bool init = false;
    T current = default(T);

    foreach (var x in sequence)
    {
        if (!init || !object.Equals(current, x))
            yield return x;

        current = x;
        init = true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: +1, but I would prefer a better name for the method... `RemoveDuplicates` is confusing because it seems to implies that all duplicates are removed, when actually only *adjacent* duplicates are removed. Perhaps something like `RemoveAdjacentDuplicates`

Comment: I don't disagree.  I believe there's some usual name for this operation which I can't summon up right now.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is! One-line code and one loop of the array.

```
int[] source = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 8, 9, 4, 4, 4 };
var result = source.Where((item, index) => index + 1 == source.Length 
                          || item != source[index + 1]);
```

And according to @Hogan's advice, it can be better:

```
var result = source.Where((item, index) => index == 0 
                          || item != source[index - 1]);
```

More readable now i think. It means "choose the first element, and those which isn't equal to the previous one".

Comment: +1: Good solution. Less readable than a non-LINQ solution, but LINQ is what the OP asked for, and this is probably the most readable LINQ based solution.

Comment: This assumes that the source collection is an array, and this is a trivial problem to solve when you have indexed access and a `Length` property. How about a solution that works on any `IEnumerable<T>` instead? (After all, the question talks about a sequence, not a list or an array.)

Comment: feh, this is shorter : `var result = source.Where((item, index) => index == 0 || item != source[index - 1]);`

Comment: @Hogan: Good catch. I'll add it into the answer.

Comment: @LukeH : I believe this works on any Enumerable, but it might not be O(n) with a sequence that does not provide array element access.

Comment: @Hogan: The original version only works as-is on a collection with a `Length` property and direct indexed access (eg, an array); the revised version doesn't need `Length` but still needs direct indexed access, so it'll need something like `IList<T>`. This can easily be changed to use `ElementAt` rather than the indexer, but then, as you say, it's no longer O(n) unless you are using `IList<T>`.

Comment: @LukeH : Or `ElementAtOrDefault`, if you never have the default value in the list (then you don't need the index check).

Comment: How would I concat this to the end of existing query? I.e. `source.Select(...).Where((item, index) => ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Aggregate()` (although I'm not sure whether it's better than the non-LINQ solution):

```
var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 8, 9, 4, 4, 4 };

var result = ints.Aggregate(
    Enumerable.Empty<int>(),
    (list, i) =>
        list.Any() && list.First() == i
        ? list
        : new[] { i }.Concat(list)).Reverse();
```

I *think* it's O(*n*), but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Probably the one most true to functional style, though. In F# it'd be something like `ints |> List.fold(fun (l, i) c -> if c <> i then (c :: l, c) else (l, c)) ([], ints.Head + 1) |> fst |> List.rev`. Now if there's a way to use `yield` or some other form of list comprehension, we're in business.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4 then you can do this using the built-in [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method, although I'd probably prefer to use a custom extension method like the one shown in [mquander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110976/linq-query-that-reduces-a-subset-of-duplicates-to-a-single-value-within-a-larger/4111007#4111007).

```
// replace "new int[1]" below with "new T[1]" depending on the type of element
var filtered = original.Zip(new int[1].Concat(original),
                            (l, r) => new { L = l, R = r })
                       .Where((x, i) => (i == 0) || !object.Equals(x.L, x.R))
                       .Select(x => x.L);
```

Comment: @Thomas: Nope, `Take(1)` is what I meant. Using `Skip` instead would break when there are dupes at the beginning of the sequence, for example `{ 1, 1, 2 }`.

Comment: You're right, I missed the Concat part, so I thought it would only return 1 item